# IntentHandler can’t read UserDefaults but Timeline can

Tags: swift, userdefaults, widgetkit

I want to read UserDefaults when a user changes the configuration for a widget, so I created an app group and added the capabilty to my main app, the widget extension and the Intent extension.

I can read and write fine between my app and the widget extension, however the UserDefaults always return `nil` in IntentHandler.swift, what could cause this?

```
// called from TimelineProvider
func example() -> String {

let sharedDefaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.myname")
  let value = sharedDefaults!.value(forKey: "myKey") as! String
// value == “Hi this works!”
}
```

But when I call `example()` from my IntentHandler value is `nil`. (It crashes)

Comment: Double check the intent capability, or remove it and add it again.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez ... Such a stupid mistake . It was only enabled for release mode, not debug. I need to take a break from this lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As EmilioPelaez commented, double check the capabilities (even if you've already done so, I didn't notice this either). My app group was only enabled for release mode, not debug. Should have noticed this sooner...